# Swift: how to reduce some sub-elements in a Set with a one-liner?

Tags: swift, reduce

I have this model:

```
struct Class {
    var field: [String: Field]
}

struct Field {
    var type: String
}
```

And this array:

```
let classes: [Class] = [
    Class(field: ["test": Field(type: "STRING"),
                  "test2": Field(type: "STRING"), 
                  "test3": Field(type: "NUMBER")]),
    Class(field: ["test": Field(type: "POINTER"),
                  "test2": Field(type: "STRING"), 
                  "test3": Field(type: "STRING")]),
]
```

I would like to reduce all the `types` properties in a Set of Strings, I tried this:

```
let result = classes.map { $0.field.reduce([], { $0 + $1.value.type }) }
```

But instead of getting a set of strings:

*What I would like to get*

> "STRING", "NUMBER", "POINTER"

I get an array of characters:

> [["S", "T", "R", "I", "N", "G", "N", "U", "M", "B"....]]

What should I write instead? Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you please include your sample input data and your desired output?

Comment: @jnpdx Thank you for your answer, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to flatten the arrays of values and then use `Set` to get rid of non-unique values:

```
let result = Set(classes.flatMap { $0.field.values }.map { $0.type })
```

If you need an `Array` instead of a `Set`, you can simply wrap the above in `Array()`